# Looping through an Array backwards (Bottom to the top) VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, for-loop

I have created an array in which each element is a number of row I want to delete from the worksheet.

The only issue is that deleting rows from the top of the worksheet would shift position of other rows.
Therefore, please advise how to loop through the array from the bottom to the top (backwards).

```
(...)
For Each r In rowArray()

    Cells(r, 5).Rows.EntireRow.Delete

Next r
(...)
```

Comment: Are the elements in your array ordered?

Comment: `For Each` loops *enumerate* an object collection, in the order determined by the enumerator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a counter loop and the step command:

```
Dim x as Integer

For x = 10 to 1 Step -1
   myWorksheet.Rows(x).Delete
Next x
```

If you have numbers in an array, it would be something like:

```
For x = ubound(myArray) to 0 step -1
   rows(myArray(x)).Delete
next x
```

Step is used to indicate how many iterations to jump, so you could use `Step 2` for every other row, or `Step -5` for every 5th row backwards.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for you contribiution.
However,there is no pattern in which does rows should be deleted so I do not belive it would work.

Comment: Have you tried it? Put the numbers of the rows you want to delete into the array and use the code I have suggested.

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you very much and sorry for doubting!

Answer (score 5):

`For Each...Next` loops vastly outperform `For...Next` loops for iterating object collections ([source](https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/)), and `For...Next` loops outperform `For Each...Next` loops for iterating an array. So, use a `For` loop if you're iterating an array, and a `For Each` loop it you're actually iterating the invidivual cells of a `Range`.

Consider using `Union` instead of iterating rows backwards, to join the rows you want to delete into a single `Range` object, which you an delete in a single worksheet operation - that will vastly outperform the backwards-loop.

```
Private Function Combine(ByVal source1 As Range, ByVal source2 As Range) As Range
    If source1 Is Nothing Then
        Set Combine = source2
    Else
        Set Combine = Union(source1, source2)
    End If
End Function
```

Something like this (untested air-code):

```
Dim toDelete As Range, i As Long
For i = LBound(rowArray) To UBound(rowArray)
    Set toDelete = Combine(toDelete, rowArray(i))
Next
If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.EntireRow.Delete
```

That way toggling `Application.Calculation` to manual, disabling `Application.EnableEvents` and setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` will have little to no impact whatsoever on overall performance, because you're only interacting with the sheet when you *have to*, whereas deleting each row individually will fire worksheet events, prompt recalculations and screen repaints at every single iteration.

Comment: I would add `If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then...`. But that's just me.

Comment: Thank you Mathieu.
I am afraid those solutions are beyond my current skillset, however, I will for sure analyze your advice and try to get a grip of it for the next challenge
For the time being I made a work around by defining "i" which grows by 1 each time rows from above are deleted.
This way by reducing "i" from the next number in the array I am removing correct row. 
(…). i = 0
 For Each r In rowArray()
    Cells(r - i, 5).Rows.EntireRow.Delete
    i = i + 1
 Next r
(…)

Comment: @DominikaZołotarew this solution is similar to when you hold down the Ctrl key as you click on the row headings of the rows you want to delete, then right-click and delete all the selected rows at once. Never alter `i` inside a `For` loop, it's very bug-prone - if you really want to delete rows one by one, use the other solution with `Step -1` instead, going bottom to top.